# Модульное тестирование webApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, async-await

Есть проблема с тестирование классов, наследуемых от ApiController. Некоторые методы API выполняются достаточно ощутимый промежуток времени. Как можно покрыть код тестами? Возможно ли использовать модель асинхронного выполнения кода?

Comment: Дополнительный момент, почему студия может не замечать Nunit тесты? У класса атрибут [TestFixture], у методов [Test] однако в окне с тестами их нет.

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Comment: вы можете использовать mock и stub объекты для облегчения работы с внешними зависимостями.

Comment: Mikhail Vaysman, безусловно, но смущает, что к примеру на выполнение метода может быть затрачено 10-15 секунд. Собтвенно, необходимо ожидание. Вот и хочется узнать, возможно ли приспособить NUnit для выполнения асинхронных операций. Хотя, пока что открытой является проблема того, что студия элементарно не видити тесты. В одном проекте все прекрасно, в другом не хочет замечать. Странно.

Comment: С тем, что не подхватываются тесты, у вас проект билдится?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для тестирования вполне можно использовать NUnit или XUnit, которые позволяют использовать асинхронные методы. Для выполнения запросов к API можно юзать удобный инструмент restsharp, все достаточно просто и понятно. Тест дожидается завершения результата работы методов restsharp и далее можно произвоить шаг Assert.